# How can I unlink Twitter from my iOS application

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, twitter

I use ALAccount manager to connect to twitter and make a request. I allow users to share their content to twitter via my app. It works perfectly fine, however if a user decides they do not want to share content to twitter via my app anymore, I would like to create a button that will unlink their twitter account from the app.

How can I achieve something like this?

(Apps that have this feature:
Instagram & Vine)

Comment: Delete the OAuth access token from wherever you stored it.

Comment: @H2CO3 put your answer below so that I may up vote it and accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applications are granted access to Twitter's API using OAuth. When an app is authorized by the user, it's given an OAuth access token. Most iOS OAuth libraries have the feature which stores this token to some persistent storage (`NSUserDefaults`, the Keychain, etc.). Find out where it is and delete it, and the user is now logged out.